# swapping variables with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, stack

```
void swap (int *px, int *py) {
int temp;
temp = *px;
*px = *py;
*py = temp;
}
```

that will swap two variables, which looks okay for me.

now if I change it to

```
void swap (int *px, int *py) {
int *temp;
*temp = *px;
*px = *py;
*py = *temp;
}
```

notice int *temp

this works anyway though, but temp is dereferenced without being initialized.

what value would this not work for?

like if i want to make a method called proc how could i gurantee the program will crash? I think I am supposed to leave something on the stack.

```
int main () {
int a = 1, b = 2;
proc(/* Some args might go here */);
swap(&a, &b);
}
```

Comment: This brings up undefined behavior for all I know.
Dereferencing and writing to NULL would've guarenteed a crash I believe.

Comment: @Magtheridon96 It is also UB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727834/c-standard-dereferencing-null-pointer-to-get-a-reference

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uninitialized pointers in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870038/uninitialized-pointers-in-code)

Answer (score 1):

Since `int` is a base type, why not just...

`void swap (int *px, int *py) {
int temp;
temp = *px;
*px = *py;
*py = temp;
}`

Answer (score 0):

What you do is relying on good luck: the uninitialized `int *temp;` uses some garbage from the stack and if you lucky enough, it's dereference will crash the program with SIGSEGV (AccessViolation on Windows), otherwise (and it's much worse!) it spoils some existing memory location's data which may crucial for the program, but it will show up much later as a mysterious geizenbug.

So the behavior of an uninitialized pointer completely depends on the state of the stack, which is virtually random: depending on what functions have been called before and what amount of data they used and their local variables.