# Aligning static array using std::aligned_storage

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++11, memory-alignment

I'm trying to implement 16-byte alignment of simple static array using **std::aligned_storage** pattern:

```
#include <type_traits>
int main()
{
    const size_t SIZE = 8;
    using float_16 = std::aligned_storage<sizeof(float) * SIZE, 16>::type;
    float_16 mas;
    new(&mas) float[SIZE];//Placement new. Is this necessary? 

    mas[0]=1.f;//Compile error while attempting to set elements of aligned array
}
```

I get the following compile-error:

> no match for «operator[]» in «mas[0]»

Then I tried to use explicit pointer casting:

```
float* mas_ = reinterpret_cast<float*>(mas);
```

but this also yields compile-error:

> invalid cast from type «float_16 {aka std::aligned_storage<32u,
>   16u>::type}» to type «float*»

Can anybody suggest me how align static array using **std::aligned_storage** correctly?

Comment: Why don't you use the pointer returned by `new`?

Comment: @avakar pointers returned by `new` do not have extended alignment.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I think avakar talk about the placement new (which is aligned). (see my answer)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, Jarod42 is correct, I was naturally talking about the placement new in the original question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use:

```
float* floats = new (&mas) float[SIZE];
```

and then you can use:

```
floats[0] = 1.f;
```

no `reinterpret_cast` at all :)

Comment: I'd worry about using placement new for an array allocation because of the extra space the allocation *might* need in order to keep track of the allocation size, which is afaik implementation-defined.

Comment: @FabioA.: Indeed, to be perfectly safe, we have to loop to make `SIZE` placement new :( or to use `std::array<float, SIZE>` or similar.

Answer (score 5):

`mas` is not a pointer. `reinterpret_cast` must involve exclusively pointer, reference, or integral types, and only in some combinations: pointers to and from integral types, pointers to pointers, references to references, or an integral type to itself. In this case you are trying to case an `std::aligned_storage<32u, 16u>::type` to a pointer. The best you could get from this would be a reference to pointer cast, but that's not allowed†.

Try casting its address to another pointer type instead: `reinterpret_cast<float*>(&mas);`.

---

† for fun: the worst you could get would be if `std::aligned_storage<32u, 16u>::type` was a pointer type. It's doubtful, since 32-byte pointers are not common, but it could happen for `std::aligned_storage<8u, 8u>::type`, for example, in a very nasty standard library. Let's call it Hell++. So, in Hell++ it would compile fine, and you would end up casting the pointer type to another pointer type, and then doing all nasties on it like dereferencing it. This would be disastrous, because if `std::aligned_storage<32u, 16u>::type` was a pointer type, objects wouldn't have the address for the storage, but they would *be* the storage instead.

Comment: It works, but can I be shure, that mas_ is really 16-byte aligned?

Comment: @gorill if it isn't, file a bug for your standard library implementation. (you can test it by reinterpret_casting the pointer as an integer and checking if it's divisible by 16)

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<float*&>(mas)` will interpret the bit pattern at `mas` as a pointer - that can't be what was intended. Use `reinterpret_cast<float*>(&mas)` instead.

Comment: @SebastianRedl oh, true! He wants an array, not a pointer. Ooops. Thanks. (And now I feel silly, after posting that note and causing the same thing here)

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes, I tried Your suggetion, but get runtime-error. Please, see addition part in my question.

Comment: Oh, please. I'm going to be blunt. You need to go learn some basic C++ before you start messing with `reinterpret_cast` and `aligned_storage`.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/46642 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/5870038/46642 and something about out parameters or return values.

Comment: @ R. Martinho Fernandes, sorry - I really screwed up)))) it is my stupid and apparent mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Just do

```
alignas(16) float mas[SIZE];
```

`std::aligned_storage` is a C++03 relic coming from `boost`.

Comment: @gorill Yeah 4.7 does not support it. Try updating your compiler to 4.8.

Comment: `aligned_storage` is not a C++03 relic. It aligns raw storage, while `alignas` aligns objects. Those are different purposes. Even though it does not make a big difference here in this particular case, `aligned_storage` provides non-redundant functionality.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Nothing you couldn't replace with a `typedef` or a `using`.