# Which data type does pointer points to?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, heap-memory

I am kind of confused with the pointers.

Say if I have this:

```
int size;
int bytes;
int numbers;
int *ptr;

ptr = new int[500];
```

My question is the pointer at first points to any specific variable or just to overall int variables. What if I want a pointer to point only at numbers variable.

I have a tail question if you don't mind. I am trying to allocate dynamic memory to my array, is this valid? :

```
int numbers[20];
int *ptr;
ptr = new int[size];
```

Would this give a heap memory to my array?

I am working with an array of very large size and there is no other way to work with it without using heap memory.

P.S: I can't use vector at this point.

Comment: To understand pointers, consider that pointers are references to actual RAM that a program exists in.  Classic strongly typed languages like C require that all variables in memory at runtime are typed.  So, for example, one can have a 4-byte block of memory set aside for a 32-bit integer type.  In order for appropriate read, write, and usage apart, the contents size and type must be directly identifiable in a static way during compilation.  It looks like your assignment would not use heap memory, and instead be treated like a normal array.  Read the docs on malloc() for dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 1):

`int *ptr` is an pointer to an `int` variable. It doesn't matter what variable, as long as it is an `int` so you could have the following.

```
int size;
int bytes;
int numbers;
int *ptr;

ptr = &size;
ptr = &bytes;
ptr = &numbers;
```

I use the `&` symbol because this gives the actual address of the variable not its value. Pointers can only store the address of a variable.

If you then wanted to use the actual values that the pointer points to, you need to deference it, like so

```
int number = 5;
int *ptr;
ptr = &number;
cout << *ptr;   
//5
```

As for your second question. Yes that would give you a valid pointer to an array on the heap.

For more information I suggest looking up what an array actually is, since you might be confused why you don't need to use the `&` symbol when assigning a pointer to an array.

Answer (score 0):

`int *ptr` is uninitialized, so it actually points to "garbage values" or in this case, random memory addresses. Check out [Uninitialized pointers in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870038/uninitialized-pointers-in-code)

If you want `int *ptr` to point to the value of numbers, you should first initialize `int numbers`, because this can cause [Undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) if you try to dereference it.

You can assign the ptr equal to `numbers` by using the Address-of operator `&`. Then use the dereference operator `*` to grab the value of `ptr`.

```
numbers = 4;
ptr = &numbers;
cout << *ptr << endl;
```

This will print `4`.

Comment: Pointing to an uninitialized variable won't cause any "undefined behavior" unless you try to dereference it.

Comment: @AlexLop. Thank you. Edited.

Comment: still, one doesn't have to initiallize a variable before pointing to it...

Comment: @AlexLop. Yeah, poor wording on my part.

Answer (score 0):

```
int arNumbers[20];
```

gives you memory from stack and is not dynamic and compiler would take care of releasing the memory.

```
int *pNumbers = new int[20];
```

gives you memory from heap and is dynamic and you need to delete it when you are done:

```
delete[] pNumbers;
```

if you need 20 numbers, one of them is enough.