# Why variable is null in Unreal Engine?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, casting, unreal-engine4

I want to call function, which changes the text inside the widget.

There is a `virtual` function `NativeConstruct`, which calls automatically. And it changes text of widget, but I need to call function `F1` and send a *text* to it, which I want to display. But when I call it, the variable `Name` is `nullptr`. And by some reason, it is not `nullptr`, when program call `NativeConstruct`.

- `Name` is my text variable, which I want to change
- `dialogBottom` is the name of widget with this variable

Edited

```
UAccessWidgetFromCpp* AccessWidgetFromCpp 
= CreateWidget<UAccessWidgetFromCpp>(
      GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController(), UAccessWidgetFromCpp::StaticClass()
   );

if (AccessWidgetFromCpp)
{
   AccessWidgetFromCpp->F1("222");
   widgetDialogBottomInstance->AddToViewport();
}

UCLASS()
class HOME_API UAccessWidgetFromCpp : public UUserWidget
{
   GENERATED_BODY()

public:
   UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, meta = (BindWidget))
   class UTextBlock* Name = nullptr;

   UFUNCTION()
   void F1(FString text);
};

void UAccessWidgetFromCpp::F1(FString text)
{
   if (auto widget = dynamic_cast<UTextBlock*>(GetWidgetFromName(TEXT("Name"))))
   {
      Name = widget;
      Name->SetText(FText::FromString(text));
   }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `UPROPERTY` the `Name` has not initialized to `nullptr` in the beginning. Therefore, it could contain [any garbage value inside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870038/uninitialized-pointers-in-code).

Initialize it to `nullptr` in the class definition or in the constructor of `UAccessWidgetFromCpp`(if any). For instance, this will fix the issue

```
UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, meta = (BindWidget))
class UTextBlock* Name = nullptr;
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Regarding the new update:

First of all, you should [avoid using c-style casting in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast). Secondly, the function [`GetWidgetFromName`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/UMG/Blueprint/UUserWidget/GetWidgetFromName/index.html) returns, *uobject widget* corresponding to a given name. Therefore you should be sure about having one with "`Name`".

Otherwise, make your code safe by double-checking the `nullptr` scenarios.

```
if(auto widget = dynamic_cast<UTextBlock*>(GetWidgetFromName(TEXT("Name")))) 
{
    Name = widget;
    Name->SetText(FText::FromString(text));
}
```

Even now you do not reach the line `Name->SetText(FText::FromString(text));` means either you have no widget called "`Name`" or it is not possible to cast the `UWidget*` to a `UTextBlock*`. You might need a redesign of how to do this.

Comment: I adder nullptr and initialize `Name` before if, because there is no dafault constructor for `UUserWidget` class, but it is still null. Added code

Comment: @DimaKozyr The function `GetWidgetFromName` returns, uobject widget corresponding to a given name. Are you sure you have a widget called "Name".? You can do `if(auto widget = dynamic_cast<UTextBlock*>(GetWidgetFromName(TEXT("Name")))) { Name = widget; }` By this you will make sure, it has been succesfully cased to parent and not `nullptr`, before assigning to the `Name`.

Comment: Thanks, for help, I edited wy question. `Name` is my text variable, which I want to change and `dialogBottom` is name of widget. And with this code `Name` is still null

Comment: @DimaKozyr Then you have your answer in front of you: 1. Could be that there is no widget called "Name" 2. It is not possible to cast the `UWidget*` to a `UTextBlock*`. You might need a redesign of how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Remember to practise defensive programming! Initialize ptr values to nullptr - never assume variables are initialised in C++. The code `if(Name)` does *not* check if a UObject is valid, it just checks that there is *some value* in the variable - and that value will be some garbage value if the variable has not been initialised.

Furthermore, I'd recommend checking variables (that might possibly be null) immediately prior to dereferencing them.

[according to the UE4 docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/UMG/Blueprint/UUserWidget/GetWidgetFromName/index.html):

> `GetWidgetFromName` returns the uobject widget corresponding to a given name

If there is no uobject widget corresponding to the given name (eg. due to a typo in the supplied text or some code logic error), the UE4 docs are not explicit and I haven't tested it personally, but I would assume that `nullptr` will be returned. If so, the null return would happen *after* your `if(Name)` check yielding a nullptr dereference.

ie.

```
void UAccessWidgetFromCpp::F1(FString text)
{
    if (Name)
    {
        Name = (UTextBlock*)GetWidgetFromName(TEXT("Name"));
        // if there is no Widget with name "Name" then the variable Name 
        // may now be null even if it wasn't at the if check earlier
        Name->SetText(FText::FromString(text));
    }
}
```

Hope that clarifies (naming the widget variable "Name" certainly doesn't help).

Comment: This is why I suggested in the comments to do `if(auto widget = dynamic_cast<UTextBlock*>(GetWidgetFromName(TEXT("Name")))) { Name = widget; Name->SetText(FText::FromString(text)); }`, which will handles these all issues.