# The initialization of ListNode

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, undefined-behavior, memory-access

I have a question about the initialization of ListNode, if I just announce a ListNode pointer, why can't I assign its next value like showed in the code.

```
struct ListNode {
     int val;
     ListNode *next;
     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
};

ListNode* tmp;
tmp->next = nullptr;// This is wrong, why is that?

ListNode* tmp2 = new ListNode(1);
tmp2->next = nullptr;// This is right, what cause that?
```

I just try to announce a ListNode pointer and assign its next value to nullptr. But after I announce a pointer with new function, it goes right. Why?

Comment: Think about what the tmp pointer points to and see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870038/uninitialized-pointers-in-code).

Comment: I assume you're doing this for some kind of assignment (which is fine). If you're not, be aware that this kind of C++ is considered outdated nowadays (at least in most contexts).

Comment: In the first case you did not initialize the pointer `tmp`. In C/C++ this means it can contain garbage. Such a pointter cannot be dereferenced (i.e. access what it points to) because it is invalid. In the second case you assign the pointer to a new object allocated with `new` and therefore it is valid and ok to access what it points to.

Comment: `tmp2->next = nullptr;// This is right, what cause that?` Since your constructor properly initialized next you did not need to do this as its redundant but it is still fine to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pointer is a box that can hold the address of an object

```
 ListNode* tmp;
 tmp->next = nullptr;// This is wrong, why is that?
```

Here you created the box (tmp) but did not put the address of an object in it.
The second line says - "at offset 4 from the address stored in tmp please write 0", well there is no valid address in the box so this fails.

In the second example

```
ListNode* tmp2 = new ListNode(1);
tmp2->next = nullptr;// This is right, what cause that?
```

You say

```
"Please make a new ListNode object"
"Put its address in the box called tmp2"
"at offset 4 from the address stored in tmp2 please write 0"
```

That can work, becuase the box tmp2 points somewhere valid

Answer (score 0):

> I just try to announce a ListNode pointer and assign its next value to
> nullptr

The pointer does not have any data members. It is an object of the type `ListNode` that has data members.

So you need an object of the type `ListNode` and using a pointer pointing to the object you can assign any value to the data member `next` of the object.

```
ListNode* tmp2 = new ListNode(1);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^
  pointer               object
```

As for this code snippet

```
ListNode* tmp;
tmp->next = nullptr;// This is wrong, why is that?
```

then neither object of the type `Listnode` exists data members of which you could change. Moreover as the pointer `tmp` is uninitialized and has an indeterminate value then using such a pointer to access memory results in undefined behavior.