# How to correctly typecast a data begin pointer (and is it even good practice)?

Tags: c++, casting

Consider a row-major, 4-channel, 8 bit image. I would like to transfer the data, pixel by pixel, to another, equally sized image. Since I have 4*8=32 bits per pixel, I would like to use the assignment `operator=` on an `int` once, instead of alternatives like `memcpy()` or using the assignment `operator=` on 4 unsigned chars (the actual layout of the data).

I have the following code with one problem:

```
CreateEquivalentImages(in, out);
for (int y = 0; y < in.rows; ++y)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < in.cols; ++x)
    {
        int* pixel = (int*)in.data + x + y*width; //line in question
        int* outpixel = (int*)out.data + x + y*width;
        *outpixel = *pixel;
    }
}
```

`(int*)in.data` is not explicit of the type of casting performed. Which typecast operation does `(int*)in.data` default to?

Is `int* pixel = reinterpret_cast<int*>(in.data) + x + y*width;` the correct way to typecast the data pointer?

Conclusion:

```
-Memcpy() and 
-typecasting data pointers into char* and then using assignment
```

are equivalent in behavior (copying raw memory) and solutions to this problem. But typecasting raw memory into another type *(even an intrinsic type like int)*, and then using assignment operator is platform-specific and hence, undefined behavior.

Comment: Know that if you had `std::vector<int>` you could simply use `=` which would do an element-by-element copy.

Comment: You shouldn't assume that `int` is 32 bits.  Use `int32_t` or `uint32_t` from `<cstdint>` instead.  (Requires C++11)

Comment: @Cyber this is true, but I do not control the data format (external library), so I cannot simply change it.

Comment: Also, I can understand not wanting to use `memcpy` on each individual 4-byte pixel, but since the arrangement of the pixels seems to be the same for both images, why not just `memcpy` the entire image in one call?  I don't see the point in doing it pixel-by-pixel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're triggering undefined behaviour by doing that. I suggest you just assign each component separately (as 4 `unsigned char` values, I assume), and rely on your compiler to perform this efficiently.

See:

- [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)
- [Strict aliasing rule and 'char *' pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848188/strict-aliasing-rule-and-char-pointers)

Comment: Brilliant! This shows how a lot of errors can be swept under the rug but then the program goes into undefined behavior-land, being at the mercy of the platform.