# Write with 8bit pointer, read with 32bit pointer

Tags: c, pointers, casting

What really happens if we write 4 times 1B of char with 8bit pointer, and then we read that 4B with 32bit pointer? Why this is not recommended, what can happen?

Comment: The result will depend on the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the system. It's therefore not portable code.

Comment: Strict aliasing does not apply since you can always alias to an 8 bit pointer.

Comment: @unwind maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848188/strict-aliasing-rule-and-char-pointers is a better duplicate

Comment: @doron Not if `CHAR_BIT > 8`.

Comment: @doron You can convert from pointer-to-x to pointer-to-char, but not the other way around. So strict aliasing does apply, assuming the "8 bit pointer" is a character type.

Comment: You are right. You will have to copy the bytes into the integer

Comment: @Rhymoid: No conforming compiler can define types uint8_t and int8_t unless CHAR_BIT==8.  A conforming compiler, however, may define integer types other than "char", "short", "int", "long", and "long long"; if it defined an 8-bit type with no padding which was none of the above, it could use the identifiers `uint8_t` and `int8_t` to identify such a type.  I would think that was a horrible idea (IMHO, there should be a pair of signed/unsigned types with some other name for that purpose) but it would allowed under the Standard.

Answer (score 0):

When you read the 32bits back as an integer you get the integer representation of whatever you wrote.

What you have described is a technique commonly used to deserialize binary data. The reverse procedure will serialize the data.