# Am I violating strict aliasing rules by creating dummy struct data types?

Tags: c, strict-aliasing

I have these two functions:

```
static inline void *ether_payload(void *pkt)
{
  return ((char*)pkt) + 14;
}
static inline uint16_t ip_id(const void *pkt)
{
  const char *cpkt = pkt;
  uint16_t id;
  memcpy(&id, &cpkt[4], sizeof(id));
  return ntohs(id);
}
```

Now, there's a type safety issue. For the first function, void pointer means Ethernet header. For the second function, void pointer means IPv4 header. This creates a huge possibility that somebody accidentally calls the second function for an Ethernet header directly. If somebody does so, the compiler gives no warning.

I would like to eliminate this type safety issue through two dummy structs the contents of which are never defined:

```
struct etherhdr;
struct ipv4hdr;
```

Now the functions would be:

```
static inline struct ipv4hdr *ether_payload(struct etherhdr *pkt)
{
  return (struct ipv4hdr*)(((char*)pkt) + 14);
}
static inline uint16_t ip_id(const struct ipv4hdr *pkt)
{
  const char *cpkt = (const char*)pkt;
  uint16_t id;
  memcpy(&id, &cpkt[4], sizeof(id));
  return ntohs(id);
}
```

This solves the type safety issue. Note I'm not actually accessing the Ethernet or IP headers through a struct which would be very bad practice indeed.

My question is, am I violating strict aliasing rules by defining such an API? Note the data is never accessed via the struct; the data is just accessed via memcpy using a char pointer. My understanding is that char pointer can alias to anything.

Let's leave the fact that Ethernet packet can contain IPv6 as irrelevant, as this was just a very simple example.

Comment: `char*` is indeed allowed to alias. I don't see any strict aliasing violations here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for answering your question, it was already answered by Cornstalks, no, you are not violating any strict aliasing rules.
You may convert a pointer to a char pointer. You may convert char pointer to another pointer if you are sure, that this another pointer is really there.
See [Strict aliasing rule and 'char *' pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848188/strict-aliasing-rule-and-char-pointers)

Comment: About your suggestion... if you do typedef void ipv4hdr, then ip4hdr* will be a void pointer, type-compatible with every other void pointer such as etherhdr*. Thus, the dummy structs are necessary.

Comment: To expand on what @juhist wrote: In your suggestion, mis-use will not give a compiler warning, which was the whole point.

Answer (score 1):

The Standard allows implementations to impose alignment restrictions for structures which are coarser than those of any items contained therein.  This would allow an implementation for a platform that only supports aligned accesses, that was given e.g.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
struct foo {uint32_t dat[1]; };
struct bar {uint16_t dat[2]; };
void test1(struct foo *dest, struct foo *src)
{
    memcpy(dest, src, 4);
}
void test2(struct bar *dest, struct bar *src)
{
    memcpy(dest, src, 4);
}
```

to generate code for `test2` which is just as efficient as for `test1` [using one 32-bit read and write, instead of two 16-bit reads and writes].  If an implementation were to always pad all structures out to a multiple of four bytes and align them to four-byte boundaries, such an implementation would be allowed to perform the aforementioned optimization on `test2` without having to know or care about how or even if `struct bar` is ever defined anywhere.

I don't know whether any present implementations would ever do such a thing, but I can hardly rule out the possibility that a future implementation might do so since there some circumstances where it could allow more efficient code generation.