# Converting hex to float

Tags: c, hex

I am parsing a header in a file.
The file has some float value it wants me to extract.
The comments say its a float32 value but I'm not sure how to extract it.

Given a buffer like this, how do I properly extract this? Note it is little endian.

```
unsigned char b[4];
b[0] = 0xa1;
b[1] = 0xb2;
b[2] = 0xc3;
b[3] = 0xd4;

float f = b[0] | b[1] << 8 | b[2] << 16 | b[3] << 24;
printf("f is %f\n", f);
```

---

To be more clear: the problem is that no matter what the value in the file (buffer) the decimal is always .000000. How do I know where that decimal should go?

Comment: Something like this? https://ideone.com/8SwJ9x

Comment: Try `printf("%g\n", (union { unsigned char b[4]; float f;}){ {0xa1, 0xb2, 0xc3, 0xd4} }.f);`

Comment: @pmg I should have cleared up: the value shouldnt be something like `-6724124147712.000000`, but more along the lines of 124.49.. Ie a float with decimal values. I just don't get where in the binary/hex representation the decimals start.

Comment: See [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: @pmg I literally don't feel smart enough to figure this out.  :*(

Answer (score 3):

The safe way:

```
unsigned char b[sizeof(float)];
float f;
memcpy(&f, b, sizeof(f));
```

it is very likely that good compiler will optimize out the call to the `memcpy` and this method will be very efficient.

gcc safe way

```
union {
  unsigned char b[sizeof(float)];
  float f;
}a = {.b = {0xa1, 0xb2, 0xc3, 0xc4}};

printf("%f" , a.f);
```

or pointer punning as in the @AnttiHaapala answer

Comment: The gcc-safe-way is considered now to be a standards-safe way, but as always compilers are not necessarily standards-compliant.

Answer (score 2):

If the target architecture has float32 as the representation, and it is of same endianness as the source, then as simple as:

```
float f;
unsigned char *b = (unsigned char *)&f;

b[0] = 0xa1;
b[1] = 0xb2;
b[2] = 0xc3;
b[3] = 0xd4;

printf("f is %f\n", f);
```

If the data source and your target architecture have little/big endianness mismatch, just reverse the indices to `3` ... `0`. If you have some other weird legacy endianness, I pity you.

---

Note that you *can* use `memcpy` - for which you would need to use an auxiliary buffer and not just something that iterates bytes; or an union which would be more code, and is not necessarily C++-compatible.

Comment: Since C99, I suspect this runs afoul of the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30875760/2410359).

Comment: @chux, the strict-aliasing rule explicitly allows accessing any object (or part of one) via an lvalue of character type.

Comment: [C11 Standard - §6.5 Expressions (p6,7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6) (last bullet) `"— a character type"`

Comment: Yes, but code here is not reading the aliased data with a character pointer, but a `float `.  The other way around is OK.  Doe not work both ways and this looks like the wrong one.

Comment: No, @chux.  The `float` object designated by `f` is being accessed via the lvalues `b[0]`, *etc*., which have type `unsigned char`.  "Access" is inclusive of both reads and writes in C Standardese.

Comment: It is a warning on `"-Wincompatible-pointer-types"` assigning the address of `float` to `unsigned char*`, but not a strict alias violation. (thus the comment from @EricPostpischil)

Comment: Yes.  The assignment requires a cast, as Eric already pointed out.  GCC provides an extension by accepting the assignment without it, but that does not factor into the strict-aliasing analysis.

Comment: @JohnBollinger To be clear you are asserting because `b` is a character pointer, with the assignment `b[0] = 0xa1;`, the compiler is obliged to note that this may change `f` and not treat `printf("f is %f\n", f);` as printing an uninitialized object?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, I am asserting that because `b` is a character pointer *that points to the first character of the object designated by `f`*, the compiler is obliged to recognize that assignments to `b[0]` ... `b[sizeof(f) - 1]` **do** modify `f`.  This does not preclude the compiler recognizing or assuming that assignments through various other `char` pointers are without any effect on `f`.

Comment: Slowly but surely I'll digest 2018 `:)`

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks.

Comment: @EricPostpischil oops, fixed, this was the last thing I did before going to bed, and it shows...