# Bug casting from bool* to void* to int*

Tags: c++, void-pointers, strict-aliasing, pointer-conversion

Often in C++, one has a parameter `void* user_data` that one can use to pass an arbitrary type.

I used this to pass an array of booleans. However, I had a bug where I cast from `bool*` --> `void*` --> `int*` and I got weird results. Here is an example.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    bool test[2] = { };
    void *ptr = static_cast<void*>(test);
    std::cout << static_cast<bool*>(ptr)[0] << '\n';
    std::cout << static_cast<int*>(ptr)[0] << '\n';
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(test[0]) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
$ g++ int_bool.cpp 
$ ./a.out 
0
-620756992
0
```

Can someone explain to me what the problem is? Normally when I cast from bool to int, there is no problem: false maps to 0 and true maps to 1. Clearly, that's not the case here.

Comment: Well you’re not allowed to cast `bool*` ➝ `void*` ➝ `int*` so it’s not surprising you got weird results.

Comment: There is no language "C/C++".  Choose one or the other — not both — unless you're asking about a difference between the languages.  Since the code is manifestly C++, I've removed the C tag.

Comment: Undefined behavior

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler To my amateur eyes, the differences between the two are irrelevant for this question.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I think the question is too far removed to be obviously an answer. I'm not an expert programmer.

Comment: Your illustrative code is pure C++.  Your use of casts is pure C++. Essentially nothing in the code is C (the line containing `main()` and the one containing `}` are valid in C).  If you want to pretend that the question is about C too, use the C subset of C++ in your code.  C and C++ are vastly different languages.  Don't try treating them as ”almost the same”.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I understand the point you are trying to make. I don't think it's relevant in this example, because my question is only about type-casting. The difference in syntax is IMHO superfluous. But thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static_cast<int*>(ptr)[0]` casts `ptr` to `int*` and reads the first element. Since the original array is only 2 bytes, you're reading outside it (because you're reading a 4-byte `int`) and invokes undefined behavior, unless `int` is a 2-byte type on your system. You're also violating the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/995714) by accessing a type using a different pointer type which also invokes UB. Besides you'll get UB if the bool array isn't [properly aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/381244/995714). On x86 it doesn't cause any problems because x86 allows unaligned access by default but you'll get a segfault on most other architectures

`static_cast<int>(test[0])` OTOH converts `test[0]` (which is a `bool`) to `int` and is a completely valid value conversion.

---

**Update:**

> The type `int*` refers to a pointer whose object is 4-bytes long, whereas `bool*` refers to a pointer whose object is 2-bytes long

No. When dereferencing a variable `var`, an amount of memory of length `sizeof(var)` will be read from memory starting from that address and treat as the value of that variable. So `*bool_ptr` will read 1 byte and `*int_ptr` will read 4 bytes from memory (if `bool` and `int` are 1 and 4-byte types respectively)

In your case the `bool` array contains 2 bytes, so when 4 bytes is read from `static_cast<int*>(ptr)`, 2 byte *inside* the array and 2 bytes *outside* the array are read. If you declared `bool test[4] = {};` (or more elements) you'll see that the `int*` dereferencing completes successfully because it reads all 4 bools that belong to you, but you still suffer from the unalignment issue

Now try changing the bool values to *nonzero* and see

```
bool test[4] = { true, false, true, false };
```

You'll quickly realize that casting a pointer to a different pointer type isn't a simple read in the old type and convert to the new type like a simple value conversion (i.e. a cast) but a different "memory treatment". This is essentially just a [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) which you can read to understand more about this problem

> I don't understand what you are saying about `char*`. You're saying casting from any type to `char*` is valid?

Casting from any other *pointer* types to `char*` is valid. Read the question about strict aliasing rule above:

> You can use `char*` for aliasing instead of your system's word. The rules allow an exception for `char*` (including `signed char` and `unsigned char`). It's always assumed that `char*` aliases other types.

It's used for things like `memcpy` where you copy the bytes representing a type to a different destination

```
bool test[4] = { true, true, true, true };
int v;
memcpy((char*)&test, (char*)&v, sizeof v);
```

Technically `mempcy` receives `void*`, the cast to `char*` is just used for demonstration

See also

- [Strict aliasing rule and 'char *' pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23848188/995714)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing

Comment: In addition to the size of the original array and reading outside of it... it's also *undefined behavior* to dereference the `bool*` as an `int*`, regardless.

Comment: “and invokes undefined behavior, unless int is a 2-byte type on your system” — This is **incorrect**. As Eljay said, this is *always* UB, regardless of type sizes.

Comment: @Eljay it's in the "violating the aliasing rule" part above

Comment: [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/10147399)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I find it confusing though, that one can convert bool to int but not bool* to int*. (Of course since it was cast to void* along the way, it doesn't know sizeof I guess).

Comment: @thedoctar `bool` to `int` is a *value* conversion so obviously there's no trouble in doing that. But `bool*` and `int*` refers to the *underlying memory representation* of the objects, and you can only access any type's representation by `char*`. Doing that with any other pointer types violate strict aliasing rule

Comment: @phuclv Thanks you, I think I understand now what you are saying. The type int* refers to a pointer whose object is 4-bytes long, whereas bool* refers to a pointer whose object is 2-bytes long. I don't understand what you are saying about char*. You're saying casting from any type to char* is valid? That is very confusing!

Comment: @phuclv Thanks! Lots of info, hope to learn and digest.