# Strict aliasing rule for character pointer C++

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing

I am trying to understand the strict aliasing rule. By reading the answer to [What is the strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/99010/2961927) , I have some further questions. Here I borrow the example from that post:

```
struct Msg { uint32_t a, b; }
void SendWord(uint32_t);
void SendMessage(uint32_t* buff, uint32_t buffSize)
{
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < buffSize; ++i) SendWord(buff[i]);
}
```

Now consider the following code (A):

```
uint32_t *buff = (uint32_t*)malloc(sizeof(Msg));
std::memset(buff, 0, sizeof(Msg));
Msg *msg = (Msg*)buff; // Undefined behavior.
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
  msg->a = i;
  msg->b = i + 1;
  SendMessage(buff, 2);
}
free(buff);
```

For the above code, the author explained what might happen due to the UB. The message sent could contain all 0s: during optimization, the compiler may assume `msg` and `buff` point to disjoint memory blocks, and then decide the writes to `msg` do not affect `buff`.

But how about the following code (B):

```
uint32_t *buff = (uint32_t*)malloc(sizeof(Msg));
std::memset(buff, 0, sizeof(Msg));
unsigned char *msg = (unsigned char*)buff; // Compliant.
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < sizeof(Msg); ++i)
{
  msg[i] = i + 1;
  SendMessage(buff, 2);
}
free(buff);
```

Is the sent message guaranteed to be as intended (as if the strict aliasing complier flag is off) ? If so, is it simply because a `*char` (`msg`) points to the same place as `buff`, the compiler should and will notice it, and refrain from the possible, aforementioned optimization in (A) ?

Yet then I read another comment under the post [Strict aliasing rule and 'char *' pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23848188/2961927), saying that it is UB to use the `*char` pointer to **write** the referenced object. So again, code (B) could still result in similar, unexpected behavior ?

Comment: Read [__Type aliasing__](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) here  Specifically allowed - _"AliasedType is std::byte, (since C++17) char, or unsigned char: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes."_

Comment: @RichardCritten That looks like it could be fleshed out into an answer.

Comment: @RichardCritten I see. So the full sentence is "Whenever an attempt is made to read or modify the stored value of an object of type DynamicType through a glvalue of type AliasedType, the behavior is undefined unless one of the following is true: (3) AliasedType is std::byte, (since C++17) char, or unsigned char". This means writing to that char pointer is valid right? I'll accept your answer if you want to flesh it out.

Comment: The answer you link to only applies to C (and furthermore, is wrong!); the strict aliasing rule is different in C and C++.

Comment: @M.M By wrong, were you referring to the second link in my post?

Comment: By "wrong" I am referring to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/99010/1505939 (the first code sample in that answer is correct in C)

Answer (score 1):

First of all , the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/99010/1505939 is applying to C (and is in fact completely wrong, but that's another story). You ask about C++ and the strict aliasing rule is set up differently in C than C++. So that answer has nothing to do with this question.

Prior to C++20, both versions of your code cause undefined behaviour (by omission) as the behaviour of the assignment operator is only defined for the case of writing to an object. The `malloc` function in C++ allocates space but does not create objects within that space.  The task should be approached using various other constructs such as `new`, or higher level containers, which do both allocate space and create objects within the space ready for writing.

Trying to analyze this code (pre-C++20) in context of the C++ strict aliasing rule is not possible because the definition of the rule is about accessing the *stored value of an object* but in this code it is not accessing any object, since no object was created.

---

Since C++20 there is a new provision (N4860 [intro.object]/10) that objects can be implicitly created by the assignment operator, if there exists such a possible combination of objects that would make the code well-defined. (Otherwise the behaviour remains undefined).

Under this change to the object model, **both of your code samples are well-defined**. In (A) there can be implicitly-created `uint32_t` objects in the space, and in (B) there can be implicitly-created `unsigned char` objects in the space. Since your code does not write as one type and then read as a different type, there is no possibility of an aliasing violation.

The existence of intermediate pointers of various types such as `buff` has no bearing on strict aliasing (in either language) -- the rule is strictly about how the space is read and written; not about how we got to the space.

Comment: I do not think this is correct. The implicitly-created object would need to be a `Msg` (with its subobjects). Otherwise `msg->a = i` is going to be undefined behavior. Passing it as `uint32_t*` is then allowed only because `Msg` is standard-layout and the first member is `uint32_t`, thus pointer-interconvertible. However, pointer arithmetic in `buff[i]` to get to the second member is then not allowed. In (B) the created objects would need to be an (array of) `uint32_t`, but accessing through `unsigned char` will be allowed.

Comment: @user17732522 well there's no `buff[i]` in the actual code samples A and B being asked about

Comment: You bring up the old question of whether `msg->a` requires all of `*msg` to exist , or just an element of the correct type for `a`,  this has never been specified clearly in the standard although I do concede that the view that all of `*msg` must exist is the more common view